# Publish WebApp to Azure MarketPlace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

My company has a direction to create web app to be published and sold on Azure Marketplace.

After reading up on the topic on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/programs/certified/, I am confused that what is actually the right way to achieve what we want to do above.

1. Do we need to create a VM as a container for our webapp so that it can be sold on Market Place? In this method, are subscribers creating their own VM service from the image we publish? I wonder how are updates/fixes being pushed out to every subscriber.
2. I then came across AppSource. In this way, are we creating/hosting the app in our azure app service, and users are authorized into the app through AAD (it looks like we have to use AAD authentication?)? Are we able to segregate user data by say, organizations?

I really appreciate if someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score -1):

For point 1, you could look at this question: [Publishing a web application on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967513/publishing-a-web-application-on-azure)

i think what you are looking for is the "solution template". it took me a while to get it, but if you look at the docs there is a comparison between "Virtual machine" and "Solution template".

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/marketplace-publishing/marketplace-publishing-getting-started):

**VM example**:

> As an Azure publisher, you've created and validated a VM with an innovative database service. Other Azure subscribers want to procure and deploy this VM into their cloud service environments.

**Solution template example**

> As an Azure publisher, you've bundled a set of services from across Azure that make it quick to deploy cloud services with load balancing, enhanced security, and high availability. Other Azure subscribers can save time by procuring the solution template that meets their objective. They don't have to manually locate, procure, deploy, and configure the same or similar Azure services.

Comment: Your answer doesn't address all OP's questions. Also, the question you mentioned as a duplicate doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: ok, you're right i'm addressing just the first point. i'll updte the answer